# How to update insert records into database with every replied-to email?

Tags: node.js, nodemailer

I'm testing sending emails to myself with Nodemailer, and I have the basic setup,

```
    const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
      service: "gmail",
      auth: {
        user: "foo@gmail.com",
        pass: "foobar"
      }
    });

    const mailOptionsUser = {
      from: "John Doe <foo@bar.com>",
      to: 'bar@foo.com',
      subject: "Test | New email",
      html: `<h3>test</h3>`
    };

    transporter.sendMail(mailOptionsUser, function(error, info) {
      if (error) {
        console.log(error);
      } else {
        console.log("Email sent: " + info.response);
      }
    });
```

I want to be able to track conversations on my web app, so that users can send emails to themselves, and they'll be able to see those messages when they log into the app.

I was thinking of using the `replyTo` feature, but that won't do what I need -- is there any way to update the database with every sent email (that isn't sent through Nodemailer)?

Comment: you can store your data to database when you get success message from sendMail

Comment: I can only store the first sent email. If a user replies to that email, I have no way of storing it to the database.

Comment: what we are doing with nodemailer here is sendMail. like that try to find something which gives you reciveMail functionality